# Do need to code for expansion files for android?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, google-play, apk-expansion-files

We have andriod based application which has image(say three sets of images in A,B,C folders)  galleries.As size of images is big in MBs we want to use expansion files.Images in eclipse resides inside assets in 3,(A,B,C)different folders.Now if i create zip files (with proper naming convention (main.versionname.packagename)) for asset folder with A.B,C folders inside it and upload to google play with main apk file, how would the application will understand which files to refer from which folder (assets > A or assets > B ).As expansion files are downloded on SD card how the application will undestand which folder / files to refer in application.Do i need to do some coding to read image files?
Do not give reference of ..
http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html..this is not solving the issue.

Comment: in question its andriod, not andrion. Its mistaken..